# Database on my discord bot (Discord.js + mysql)

Tags: mysql, discord, bots, discord.js

Well, I am making a discord bot and I want to implement a mysql database on it.

I've researched how to connect an online database on my bot that use Node.js, but I've failed.

I want to know whether I have to install MySQL on my computer or there is a way to connect it online. I'm very confuse.

One more thing: If I have to install it on my PC, is there a way to upload the bot and the database together?

Help me, please.

(I'm Brazilian, so some words or sentences may be wrong)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [NodeJS MySQL client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#introduction) for connecting to your database:

```
const { createConnection } = require('mysql');

const database = createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'db',
});

database.connect();
```

As for installing and setting up MySQL, between a [local install](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) and a [containerized install](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container), I'd recommend containerizing it with [Docker](https://www.docker.com/get-started).

This can get you started via [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/): `docker-compose up`.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  database:
```

Comment: Thank you, but docker is a little complex for me. I've solved the question using MongoDB. Thank you anyway!